# How do you get the correct ISO week number from a date using Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried using the following piece of code to extract the correct iso weeknumber for this year, e.g. 07/01/2019 using the following code but it is still returning a week number that is a calendar rather than iso based, i.e. week 1 rather tha week 2. Bit stumped to be honest. NLS_TERRITORY set to UK if that makes any difference?

```
to_number(to_char(to_date(date_created,'DD/MM/YYYY'),'IW')) as WEEK_PRODUCED
```

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

Comment: What is the data type of column `date_created`?

Comment: Week 1 is until 6/1/2019 23:59:59 I think

Comment: ISO weeks should be independant of any language setting. When I try it with a hard coded 07/01/2019 I get week 2

Comment: Format `IW`, ie. Week according to ISO-8601 does not depend on any NLS-Settings. That's the purpose of this standard.

Comment: Hi, yes it's the 7th Jan that is returning week 1 using the above code which I believe should be returned as week 2. Sorry, not sure how to display data types but it worked last year using the WW value as 1st January was a Monday but not this year hence trying to use the ISO IW parameter?

Comment: You can query `all_tab_columns` to check the data type. I expect it is a real date, and your `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` has a 2-digit year (query `nls_session_paramers` to check); and that possibly you're using a client (Toad?) that ignores that NLS setting and formats the date for display as DD/MM/YYYY anyway - that would explain some of the confusion in what you're doing, anyway...?

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be because of implicit date conversion - assuming that `date_created` is actually a `DATE` column not a string. If your NLS settings are set to show dates with 2-digit years, e.g the still-default `'DD-Mon-RR'` format, then your conversion of the date value to a string and back again is losing the century. As a demo, providing your date value via a CTE:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-Mon-RR';

with your_table (date_created) as (
  select date '2019-01-07' from dual
)
select
  to_char(date_created) as nls_date,
  to_char(date_created, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as iso_date,
  to_char(to_date(to_char(date_created), 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as conv_date,
  to_number(to_char(to_date(date_created,'DD/MM/YYYY'),'IW')) as WEEK_PRODUCED
from your_table;

NLS_DATE  ISO_DATE   CONV_DATE  WEEK_PRODUCED
--------- ---------- ---------- -------------
07-Jan-19 2019-01-07 0019-01-07             1
```

Notice that the `conv_date`, which has been converted to a string using the NLS 2-digit year model, and then back to a date using a 4-digit year model, has lost it's century; you seem the same with literals:

```
select to_char(to_date('01/07/19', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;

TO_CHAR(TO
----------
0019-07-01
```

because 19 is, well, year 19; there's no hint or mechanism here to assume you meant this century. (That's what the `RRRR` format model is for.)

So, you're getting the ISO week number for January 7th in the year 19, not the year 2019, and in that year it was ISO week 1.

If your session had a 4-digit year model then it would work:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD/MM/YYYY';

with your_table (date_created) as (
  select date '2019-01-07' from dual
)
select
  to_char(date_created) as nls_date,
  to_char(date_created, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as iso_date,
  to_char(to_date(to_char(date_created), 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') as conv_date,
  to_number(to_char(to_date(date_created,'DD/MM/YYYY'),'IW')) as WEEK_PRODUCED
from your_table;

NLS_DATE   ISO_DATE   CONV_DATE  WEEK_PRODUCED
---------- ---------- ---------- -------------
07/01/2019 2019-01-07 2019-01-07             2
```

The implicitly-generated string now has a 4-digit year, so converting it back preserves the original century. (You'd still have issues with BCE dates, of course...)

But you shouldn't be converting the original date at all. Just do:

```
to_number(to_char(date_created,'IW')) as WEEK_PRODUCED
```

as in, with the same CTE:

```
with your_table (date_created) as (
  select date '2019-01-07' from dual
)
select
  to_number(to_char(date_created,'IW')) as WEEK_PRODUCED
from your_table;

WEEK_PRODUCED
-------------
            2
```

which will work whatever your NLS settings are, as there is no longer any implicit conversion going on.

Comment: Wow, that's worked...thanks so much Alex and everyone else that has commented, what a great bunch of people you are. I'm a bit taken back by how helpful and quick the responses were, really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. It's quite common to see unnecessary/accidental implicit conversions like this, and they tend to cause problems and can be hard to spot. We also quite often see people doing things like `to_date(sysdate)`, which is pointless at best but can also cause issues. So keep an eye out for implicit conversions in your code, and reliance on NLS settings.